# Creating nested associative arrays in Oracle 11g

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, associative

I have defined associative array in Oracle as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE outlier AS OBJECT (
 ACCOUNT_ID  varchar2(100),
   INC_MONTH date,
    ); 

create or replace type outlier_acc_tab as table of outlier ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE outlier_detail_rec AS OBJECT (

 NAME varchar2(100),
 OUTLIER_ACCOUNT_LIST outlier_acc_tab

);

create or replace type outlier_detail_tab as table of outlier_detail_rec;
```

Currently I am getting names repeated in  all the OUTLIER_ACCOUNT_LIST array. Instead I want to group multiple account details for a single name. Please let me know how the definition of arrays should be modified. Thanks for your help.

I am looking for an output like this

```
"OUTLIER_LIST":    [
        {
     "NAME": "A",
     "OUTLIER_ACCOUNT_LIST":          [{
        "ACCOUNT_ID": "361",
        "INC_MONTH ": 1475208000000

     }
  }, 
             {
        "ACCOUNT_ID": "362",
        "INC_MONTH": 1475208000000,

     }
  }
             ]
]
}
```

My select statement in the package is

```
  SELECT outlier_detail_rec (
          NAME   => NAME,
     outlier_acc_tab (
            outlier_acc_rec(
               ACCOUNT_ID                   => ACCOUNT_ID,
               INC_MONTH         =>  INC_MONTH

) ))
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_outlier_array
    FROM outlier_Sel;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have are not oracle [Associative Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969), they are oracle [Nested Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99981).  However, bulk collection does not work with Associative Arrays, but it does with Nested Tables.

An associative array of outlier_account_lists would be:

```
TYPE outlier_detail_aa AS TABLE OF outlier_acc_tab INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
```

To load such an AA you'll need to do something like this:

```
declare
  type outlier_detail_aa as table of outlier_acc_tab index by varchar2(100)
  outlier_detail outlier_detail_aa;
begin
  for r in (select distinct name from outlier_sel)
  loop
    select outliser_acc_rec(account_id, inc_month)
      bulk collect into outlier_detail(r.name)
      from outlier_sel
     where name = r.name;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement "bulk collection does not work with Associative Arrays" is wrong.
Bulk collect into also works with associative arrays.

```
type units_rec is record(...)
type unit_tab is table of units_rec index by binary_integer; -- <--associative array
volume_units unit_tab;

select distinct some columns
bulk collect into wul_units
from <table>;
```

but it will not work for a nested assiociative array. In your case you will need to fill the arrays "manually" with a cursor loop. I never used object (only record) so I don't know the exact syntax. But it should look like

-> create a associative array index by binary integer, where the index will be the account id

-> create a record for outlier_list, where one column is of type of the array created above, and then an associative array from this record (or try it with objects)

```
i number:=0;

for crs in (SELECT <columns> FROM outlier_Sel) loop
  outlier_list(i).name := crs.outlier_list_name;
  outlier_list(i)(crs.account_id) := crs.account_name;
  ...
end loop;
```